# Get '415 Unsupported Media Type' response status when sending request to defect tracking tool for creating issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jira-rest-api

Following is my request(from my .js file) for creating issue in defect tracking tool via rest api.

But i get the response status as **415 Unsupported Media Type** , Is there any problem in my request or some other problem?

```
 $.ajax({
                        "type": 'POST',
                        "url": 'https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue/',
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",                     
                        "data":JSON.stringify({
                                "fields": {
                                    "project":
                                    {
                                        "key": "TEST"
                                    },
                                    "summary": testCaseName,
                                    "description": description,
                                    "priority": {
                                        "name": priority
                                    },
                                    "issuetype": {
                                        "name": "Bug"
                                    }
                                }
                            }),
                        "dataType": "application/json",                                     
                        "success": function() {
                            alert("success");
                        },
                        "error":function(){
                            alert("failure");
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `Content-Type` to `contentType`, find `.ajax()` documentation [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: AS per the document it is right but i found in some of the examples it is 'Content-Type'. I also change 'Content-Type' to 'contentType' in above request But the request type  change at time of requesting into 'OPTIONS' from 'POST'

Comment: sorry I don't get your point.. anyway I've made a test with your ajax request, changing to `contentType` worked and the request passed - no 415 error (but did not work because it requested some kind of authentication)